# Issue with ItkVtkGlue

Tags: c++, vtk, itk

I'm trying to run this example: http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/IO/ImageFileReader

But, get the following when I "configure" in CMake:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package):
By not providing "FindItkVtkGlue.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
"ItkVtkGlue", but CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ItkVtkGlue" with
any of the following names:

ItkVtkGlueConfig.cmake
itkvtkglue-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "ItkVtkGlue" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"ItkVtkGlue_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If
"ItkVtkGlue" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
been installed.
```

It seems I need "ItkVtkGlue"? Where can I download it? And, what should I do to combine it with the program?

Answer (score 4):

`VtkGlue` is a module within `ITK`, which by default is not built.  You need to enable this module with cmake when you build `ITK`.  Also, before you do this, you need to download and build `VTK` (which is very similar to building `ITK`).  Assuming you are on a unix-like system, have `VTK` installed, have a `src` and `bin` folder for `ITK`, and are sitting in the `bin` folder, I would do:

```
$ ccmake ../src -DModule_ItkVtkGlue=ON
```

The last option turns the `ItkVtkGlue` module on by default.  You can also do this in the curses GUI without passing this option: press `t` to get the advanced options, use the arrow keys to scroll down to `Module_ItkVtkGlue`, and, once there, use the enter key to toggle this option `ON`.  Finally, configure, configure, configure, generate as usual, and then:

```
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Many of the [examples on the `ITK` Wiki](https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples) use `VtkGlue`.  You can see how to format your `CMakeLists.txt` file by looking at any of those.